# Rails Building an Object that has a Parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following two models in my app Spaces which are like projects & Permissions

```
class Space < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :permissions
 has_many :users, :through => :permissions

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :space
  belongs_to :role
  validates_presence_of :space_id , :user_id, :role_id
```

So here's what I'd like to do, in the Space Controller, when the user does DEF CREATE, I want to create a space, and a permission with role_id = 1, to ensure the space/project as the creator as a member...

Here's what I have. It's getting messy and not creating the permission

Space Controller:

```
def create
  @space = current_user.spaces.new(params[:space].merge(:creator => current_user.id))
  @space.permissions.new(:role_id => 1, :user_id => current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @space.save
    ..
    ..
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you should be doing this with callbacks in models, not in your controller. Can you be more specific about when you want the space created. Such as when new user or when a new space is getting created etc...

Comment: @Sam. Thanks. What do you mean by callbacks in models? Can you provide an example? Thansk... I want this to happen when a user creates a new space.

Answer (score 2):

Callbacks are how rails deals with business logic that applies to models or their associations after one of the CRUD actions.

for example. If you want to create a space with 1 permission and that permission has one role you can do something like this.

in your user model

```
def before_create
   User.permissions << Permision.create({:role_id => 1})
end
```

Take a look at call backs in [rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). They will take a lot of your logic out of the controller and make it easier to maintain in your model.